# Event not triggering in UISlider programatically created in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have the following UICollectionViewCell subclass that I have a UISlider created without using storyboards:

```
class ProductDetailPersonalLoanViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    let valueSlider: UISlider = {
        let mySlider = UISlider(frame:CGRect(x: 10, y: 100, width: 300, height: 20))
        mySlider.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        mySlider.minimumValue = 0
        mySlider.maximumValue = 100
        mySlider.isContinuous = true
        mySlider.tintColor = UIColor.green
        mySlider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sliderValueDidChange(_:)), for: .valueChanged)


        return mySlider
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect){
        super.init(frame: frame)

        setupViews()
    }

    func setupViews(){
        addSubview(valueSlider)

        // ....... layout constraints
    }

    func sliderValueDidChange(_ sender:UISlider!){
        print("Slider value changed")
        let roundedStepValue = round(sender.value / step) * step
        sender.value = roundedStepValue

        print("Slider step value \(Int(roundedStepValue))")
    }

}
```

The problem is that for some reason the event is not being triggered when I move the thumb, so I'm not able to use the UISlider value. Does someone know how to fix that?

Comment: Did you try to initialize `valueSlider` at `setupViews()` function. Like moving all `mySlider` code to there and adding it as a subview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add target to your `valueSlider` outside of the computed value block:

```
 let valueSlider: UISlider = {
    let mySlider = UISlider(frame:CGRect(x: 10, y: 100, width: 300, height: 20))
    mySlider.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    mySlider.minimumValue = 0
    mySlider.maximumValue = 100
    mySlider.isContinuous = true
    mySlider.tintColor = UIColor.green

    return mySlider
}()

override init(frame: CGRect){
    super.init(frame: frame)

    setupViews()
    valueSlider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sliderValueDidChange(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
}
```

or, which I think would be a better solution, change the computed value to a lazy property:

```
lazy var valueSlider: UISlider = {
    let mySlider = UISlider(frame:CGRect(x: 10, y: 100, width: 300, height: 20))
    mySlider.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    mySlider.minimumValue = 0
    mySlider.maximumValue = 100
    mySlider.isContinuous = true
    mySlider.tintColor = UIColor.green
    mySlider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sliderValueDidChange(_:)), for: .valueChanged)

    return mySlider
}()

override init(frame: CGRect){
    super.init(frame: frame)

    setupViews()

}
```